# Can UILabel constraint have both min and max height?

Tags: ios, constraints

I would like my label to be at least a certain height and a maximum of another height. How do I achieve this with constraints?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating two height constraints and change their `relations` to `Greater Than or Equal` for the minimum height and `Less Than or Equal` for the maximum height.

In Interface Builder you can change the `Relation` in the `Size Inspector` of the `Constraint`.

[image: Change Relation in Xcode]

To add a second height constraint is as easy as adding any other constraint. Add the second one as you do with the first.

**Example:**

[image: Adding constraints in Xcode]

After that you just have to follow the way I described above.

Comment: I guess the real question is, how do I add a 2nd height constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Get an outlet to the height layout constraint.

Here is the objective C version :

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelHeight;`

Now you set the check the height of the label (probably in ViewWillAppear) and then set it to its min or max height based on your logic.